# Forge and replay single TCP packets with mitmproxy

Tags: tcp, mitmproxy, replay

I discovered [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) and would like to use it to simulate a replay attack.

The application uses [MTProto](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto) on top of TCP, and I would like to replay entire MTProto messages.

My idea:

1. Route traffic from client to server over a proxy
2. Sniff all TCP packets
3. Replay single TCP packets

The last part is the difficult part. The forged TCP packet must

- increase the sequence number,
- recompute the checksum

in order to get accepted.

I tried to use mitmproxy for this, but I only found out how to copy the entire flow, but not single packets.

Is it possible to achieve my goal with mitmproxy? If so, how to forge a single packet?
Otherwise: Are there better tools for this attack?

Comment: May be a specialized TCP interception proxy suits better your needs: https://blog.susanka.eu/how-to-modify-general-tcp-ip-traffic-on-the-fly-with-trudy/

Comment: You can't inject specific packets with mitmproxy, but you can inject additional bytes into a live connection using the `inject.tcp` command. Does that help?

Comment: Good idea! This led me to the solution!

Answer (score 0):

The following add-on does the job for me solution (similar in spirit to [Susanka](https://blog.susanka.eu/how-to-modify-general-tcp-ip-traffic-on-the-fly-with-trudy/)):

```py
class Replayer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 0
        self.saved = None

    def tcp_message(self, flow):
        message = flow.messages[-1]
        if len(str(message)) > 700:
            if self.saved is None:
                self.saved = message.content
            else:
                message.content = self.saved
                self.saved = None


addons = [
    Replayer()
]
```